# Customized Sound from a Specific Person in Gmail

Tags: applications, gmail

I retrieve gmail message in my android and if I retrieve email from a specfic person with the following address for instance "....@test.com" I would like to retrieve the message with another sound instead of using the standard incoming sound message.

Is it possibly to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this can be done natively in an app like Gmail or Inbox, or even full blown mail clients like K-9, but there are email notification apps like Email Notifier, Mail Alert, and E-Notifier (just to name a few) where if you disable the embedded notifications in Gmail/Inbox and allow them to manage your notifications you can assign a specific notification tone based on the sender. Another option would be WhoIsIt, but that allows customized notifications for much more than just email, but text messages, phone calls, and some other apps as well.